# Scan a 2D diagonal array in Java right to left?

Tags: java

My code is actually scanns the array left to right:

```
package diagonals;

public class Diagonal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = {{20, 19, 18, 17, 16},
                         {30, 31, 32, 33, 34},
                         {44, 45, 46, 47, 48},
                            {74, 55, 76, 77, 78},
                        {61, 62, 63, 64, 65}
        };

        int width = 5;
        int height = 5;    
        int startRow = height - 1;
        int startColumn = 0;
        int column = 0;

        do {

            int row = startRow;
            column = startColumn;

            do {

                System.out.print(matrix[row][column] + " ");

                ++row;
                ++column;

            } while ((row < height) && (column < width));

            System.out.println("");

            if (startRow > 0) {

                --startRow;
            } else {

                ++startColumn;
            }
        } while (startColumn < width);

    }
}
```

My outout via this code:

```
61 
74 62 
44 55 63 
30 45 76 64 
20 31 46 77 65 
19 32 47 78 
18 33 48 
17 34 
16
```

How to change this code to scan the array from the button left to right top?

My intented output:

```
65
78 64
48 77 63
34 47 76 62
16 33 46 55 61
17 32 45 74
18 31 44
19 30
20
```

I have tried to chage the startColumn to height-1 but it outputs only 65, the first number of the scan.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the requirements of the input and the output? You are always given a square matrix of nxn and what's the output requirements?

Answer (score -1):

```
   public static void main(String []args){
           int[][] matrix = {{20, 19, 18, 17, 16},
                 {30, 31, 32, 33, 34},
                 {44, 45, 46, 47, 48},
                 {74, 55, 76, 77, 78},
                 {61, 62, 63, 64, 65}
       }  ;

    int width = 5;
    int height = 5;    
    int startRow = height - 1;
    int startColumn = width - 1;
    int column = 0;

    do {

        int row = startRow;
        column = startColumn;

        do {

            System.out.print(matrix[row][column] + " ");

            ++row;
            --column;

        } while ((row < height) && (column > -1));

        System.out.println("");

        if (startRow > 0) {

            --startRow;
        } else {

            --startColumn;
        }
    } while (startColumn > -1);



 }
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your problem statement correctly, you can try this.

```
 
class Diagonal {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        int[][] matrix = {{20, 19, 18, 17, 16},
                          {30, 31, 32, 33, 34},
                          {44, 45, 46, 47, 48},
                          {74, 55, 76, 77, 78},
                          {61, 62, 63, 64, 65}};
 
        int height = matrix.length;
        int width = matrix[0].length;
        for (int d = height * 2 - 1; d > 0; d--) {
            int column = width - 1;
            if (d < width) {
                column = d - 1;
            }
            for (int i = d - column - 1; i < height && column >= 0; i++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][column] + " ");
                column--;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
65 
78 64 
48 77 63 
34 47 76 62 
16 33 46 55 61 
17 32 45 74 
18 31 44 
19 30 
20
```